# Need to stack / combine multiple columns in excel into 1 set

Tags: excel

Edit, I have used VSTACK which works but is still has a manual element.

I have the following data, the master is much larger:

| ID | Scheme | Previous ref | ID | Scheme | Previous ref | ID | Scheme | Previous ref |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19746 | 6 | 195967001 | 36402 | 6 | 49436004 | 36313 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 24362 | 6 | 195967001 | 36479 | 6 | 49436004 | 36478 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 33686 | 6 | 195967001 | 37169 | 6 | 49436004 | 36571 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 36304 | 6 | 195967001 |  |  |  | 36691 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 36313 | 6 | 195967001 |  |  |  | 36733 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 36365 | 6 | 195967001 |  |  |  | 36900 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 36372 | 6 | 195967001 |  |  |  | 36928 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 36454 | 6 | 195967001 |  |  |  | 37203 | 6 | 363346000 |

However I need to try and get it shifted somehow without having to copy and paste all of the sets.  What you can see here is 3 sets where as I have at least 13 so it's labor intensive.

Is there a similar way to make it look like this?

| ID | Scheme | Previous ref |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19746 | 6 | 195967001 |
| 24362 | 6 | 195967001 |
| 33686 | 6 | 195967001 |
| 36304 | 6 | 195967001 |
| 36313 | 6 | 195967001 |
| 36365 | 6 | 195967001 |
| 36372 | 6 | 195967001 |
| 36454 | 6 | 195967001 |
| 36402 | 6 | 49436004 |
| 36479 | 6 | 49436004 |
| 37169 | 6 | 49436004 |
| 36313 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 36478 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 36571 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 36691 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 36733 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 36900 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 36928 | 6 | 363346000 |
| 37203 | 6 | 363346000 |

Comment: There are many ways from vba to the new VSTACK() function to power query.  What have you tried and where did it fail?  We are not here to do the work for you or to give you pointers.  This is a site to help overcome specific problems with existing code.  Please [edit] the post to include a [mcve].  Also be more specific to the method by which you wish to resolve this.

Comment: Appreciate the response Scott. Will edit tomorrow (BST time).  I tried the transpose method via Kutools. Either way I’ll have another crack at it and if needed come back with a more succinct request for support if needed.

Comment: Also, to make your data example useful, kindly edit your question to post it as text which can be copy/pasted, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac).  As written, it should adjust for extra columns/rows.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the **Main Query** M Code below in place of what you see.
- To add the Custom function

  - Right click in the Queries Pane
  - `New Query => Other Sources => Blank Query`
  - Rename the query (`Query Settings Pane - Properties - Name`):`fnPivotAll`
  - Paste the **Custom Function** M code into that window.
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

*Note that if you require that the ID's be in the same order as shown in your table, we will have to add some steps to sort the data accordingly*

***Main Query***

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table10"]}[Content],

//set the data types
//  Assumes columns in groups of three
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
            List.Zip(
                {Table.ColumnNames(Source), 
                List.Repeat({type text, type number, type text}, Table.ColumnCount(Source)/3)})),

//Unpivot all Columns to create two column table
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//split off the terminal digit(s) in the Attribute column
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), {"Attribute"}),

//Pivot the Attribute column using custom function for improved performance
    Pivot = fnPivotAll(#"Split Column by Character Transition","Attribute","Value"),

//set the data types
    Types = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Pivot, List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Pivot), {type text, type number, type text}}))
in
    Types
```

***Custom Function***

```
//credit: Cam Wallace  https://www.dingbatdata.com/2018/03/08/non-aggregate-pivot-with-multiple-rows-in-powerquery/

//Rename:  fnPivotAll 

(Source as table,
    ColToPivot as text,
    ColForValues as text)=> 

let
     PivotColNames = List.Buffer(List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source,ColToPivot))),
     #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, PivotColNames, ColToPivot, ColForValues, each _),
 
    TableFromRecordOfLists = (rec as record, fieldnames as list) =>
    
    let
        PartialRecord = Record.SelectFields(rec,fieldnames),
        RecordToList = Record.ToList(PartialRecord),
        Table = Table.FromColumns(RecordToList,fieldnames)
    in
        Table,
 
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Values", each TableFromRecordOfLists(_,PivotColNames)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",PivotColNames),
    #"Expanded Values" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Values", PivotColNames)
in
    #"Expanded Values"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ron, much appreciated.  Will give that one a go later.  Regards